# PHP global variable is null inside a function, but is not null outside it

Tags: php, function, global-variables

I've run into an error, where global seems to not work properly and can't access variable.

Here's my code:

```
function getComments($id)
{
    global $conn;
    $COMPONENT_NAME = "view_company_comments";
    include_once "validateUser.php";
```

Just for context, if `COMPONENT_NAME` isn't going to be present in some defined list, script execution will stop using die() function.

Now inside "validateUser.php":

*(explained everything in comments)*

```
   <?php

   if (!isset($COMPONENT_NAME)) {
        die(json_encode(["error" => "validating user: component was not set."]));
    } else {

        include_once "permissions.php";
        $validateUser_allowedActions = permissionsInitActions();

        //So far in, var_dump($COMPONENT_NAME) works properly here, and I get the component name succesfully. 
        //But watch next:

        //"permissionsAllowed()" is a function from "permissions.php", 
        //this function returns "false" here, expected result is "true"

        if (!permissionsAllowed($validateUser_allowedActions)) {
            die(json_encode(["error" => $COMPONENT_NAME . ": Unvalidated user privillege."]));
        }
    }
```

And inside "permissions.php":

```
function permissionsAllowed($actions)
{
    global $COMPONENT_NAME, $conn;

    //Here, var_dump($COMPONENT_NAME) results to "null", which is weird
    //because in "validateUser.php" it is a correct string value.

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM permission_actions WHERE `name` = '$COMPONENT_NAME'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $actionID = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)["id"];
    var_dump($COMPONENT_NAME);

    if (in_array($actionID, $actions)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What is happening here? What am I missing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Would moving away from `global` variables be an option, if you can I would highly recommend doing so.

Comment: @NigelRen Tried, it works fine without `global` just by passing the value, but I'm still wondering whether am I making a mistake somewhere in the code logic, or I've just found another reason to hate working with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$COMPONENT_NAME` is not a global variable in `getComments`. Although you have declared it `global` in `permissionsAllowed`, it is not declared `global` in `getComments` and thus `$COMPONENT_NAME` in `getComments` is local to that scope and hence not visible via `global $COMPONENT_NAME` in `permissionsAllowed`.

Consider the following code ([demo](https://3v4l.org/14JmP)):

```
$b = 5;

function f1 () {
    global $a;
    $a = 4;
    $b = 3;
    $c = 2;
    f2();
}

function f2 () {
    global $a, $b, $c;
    var_dump($a);
    var_dump($b);
    var_dump($c);
}

f1();
```

Output:

```
int(4)
int(5)
NULL
```

`$a` is not declared at the top level but is declared `global` in `f1` and `f2` - modifications made to it in `f1` can be seen in `f2`.
`$b` is declared at the top level, but only `global` in `f2`. `$b` in `f1` is local to that scope and changes to it have no effect on `$b` in `f2`.
`$c` is not declared at the top level and is only `global` in `f2`. Again, `$c` in `f1` is local to that scope and changes to it have no effect on `$c` in `f2`, so the `global $c` that is referred to in `f2` has no value (`null`) since it is not set anywhere.

Comment: But if I declare `COMPONENT_NAME` outside the function, it becomes global right?

Comment: @Nick only if you **also** declare it global inside `getComments`. See https://3v4l.org/TfbFK for an example

Comment: Oh well, thanks for explaining me such a uNick behaviour of variable scopes in PHP!

Answer (score 0):

Also, a variable in an Include file that is then treated as global in a contained function must also have a 'global' declaration, because an Include file is not the topmost file context, where 'global' is not required.